# PHPUnit - The test case was unexpectedly terminated: Debug Error: Class not found: Interface not found

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit, zend-studio, bjyauthorize

I get this class of error:  `Debug Error: Class/Interface not found`
And more abstract one from PHPUnit: `The test case was unexpectedly terminated.`

Specific Example:

```
Debug Error: /vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/src/BjyAuthorize/Provider/Role/ZendDb.php line 22 - Interface 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ProviderInterface' not found
```

## Steps to Reproduce

using Zend Studio 10.5.0 on PHP Version - 5.4 on Windows 7 64

- Create a new workspace (File -> Switch Workspace -> Other).  You can always switch back.
- Create a Local PHP Project (File -> New -> Local PHP Project)
- Switch to directory where the project files are located
- From command line or console, Run:

```bsh
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
php composer.phar require bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize:1.4.*
```

- In Studio, go to the `/vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/tests` folder, Right Click -> Run As -> PHPUnit Test
- A similar error will be issued.

In my case it was:

```
Debug Error: /vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/tests/BjyAuthorizeTest/Provider/Role/ZendDbTest.php line 38 - Class 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb' not found
```

The class is located here:  `/vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/BjyAuthorize/Provider/Role/ZendDb.php`, but PHPUnit is not finding it.

**Other observations**

It appears to me that PHPUnit is not namespace aware, or maybe it is an autoloader issue, or PHPUnit Bootstrap.php issue, or PHPUnit TestConfiguration.php issue.

Comment: I've also been running into what seems like the same error.  Except of in my case, literally five minutes ago my PHPUnit test worked.  I didn't change a thing, and ran it just now.  I get: "<terminated>CryptsyInterface_Test.php [PHPUnit]" with no other error messages.